# Determine the parameter range for Grid Search in ARIMA (p,d,q)

Tags: python, arima, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm trying to do a monthly price prediction model for houses in Python. I am now configuring the hyperparameter using grid search. what should be the
range of p/d/q_values based on attached ACF/PACF?

The instances are 299 months. I am currently testing p(0;13), d(0;4), q(0;13).
but its taking forever

```
# evaluate an ARIMA model for a given order (p,d,q) and return RMSE
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order):
    
    # prepare training dataset
    X = X.astype('float32')
    train_size = int(len(X) * 0.50)
    train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
    history = [x for x in train]
    
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit()
        yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test[t])
        
    # calculate out of sample error
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
    return rmse
 
# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                try:
                    rmse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order)
                    if rmse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = rmse, order
                    print('ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (order,rmse))
                except:
                    continue
    print('Best ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))
 

# evaluate parameters
p_values = range(0,13)
d_values = range(0, 4)
q_values = range(0, 13)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
evaluate_models(df.values, p_values, d_values, q_values)
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

High order ARIMA models will take for ever to compute and have a tendency to overfit. They should not be more than 10 summed up (p + d + q <= 10). I would not suggest to use GridSearch, you're better to use functions like `auto_arima()` fom `pmdarima`:

https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html
https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-using-auto-arima-in-python-bb83e49210cd

If you want to estimate the orders with the ACF/PACF, you can follow this here:
[https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim3.htm)

If the ACF is trailing off and the PACF has a sharp drop-off after a lag, then use this lag as AR component (p). If the PACF is trailing off and the ACF has a sharp drop-off after a lag, then use this lag as MA component (q). The differencing component (d) depends on whether your data is stationary or not, you can check that with the ADF test:
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html
https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-stationary-python/

In your case you probably need something like `ARIMA(3, d, 3)` but better check that with `auto_arima()`.